# How do I get rid of (1) after android studio project files?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Image 1] So I have been working on an app for a project in the android studio for school. Since I am working on it both at home and at school, I uploaded my project to google drive to access it at school. However, when I downloaded the project, unzipped it, and opened it in Android Studio, nothing is showing up and I can't build, clean, or run anything for it. I attached pictures. I suspect this may be due to the fact that since I already uploaded a version of my project to drive before, it added (1) to the end of almost every file in the project. I'm not sure whether this is causing the problems in the android studio. How do I remove them, any suggestions?  [image: Image 2]

Comment: do not open just use " import android studio project "

Comment: It looks like everything was copied for some reason.

Comment: I tried to import, but it warned me that whitespace would cause problems

Comment: I need to remove the (1) at the end of every file in a practical way

Comment: in OS open project folder and remove all (1) from names. for example search for (1) in main project folder and remove (1) from all files and folder names (rename theme in windows explorer or any OS you are using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok looks like there is actually no way to do this, oof